# How display latest article title in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm new in Drupal 8, I have a list of articles. I want to show just the title of the **latest article** and hide it in the other articles. Is there a way to do that using the views?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong you would be able to first sort articles by created time, to show you newest first, and then to limit filter to show only one.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to show all the articles too without titles and the latest one with title.